# CMake: add compile flag for header only library

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags, header-only

Unsure about how to use CMake properly here. I have one library, which is a template header only library which uses C++20 features. Therefore, I want to make sure that any [downstream/consumer/dependent] of my library compiles the specialization of my library with the correct flags.

First lib does the following:

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE include/foo.h)
```

Now, `foo` uses the filesystem stuff from c++20, so I want to do something like this:

```
target_compile_features(foo INTERFACE cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE stdc++fs)
```

In my dependent, I then want to do

```
add_executable(bar src/bar.cpp)
find_package(foo REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

```
// src/bar.cpp
#include "foo.h" // or something like that
```

Currently, linker fails. What's the proper way to set this up?

Comment: Where does your find/package configuration script come from. A handmade one containing the first 2 lines in combination with the appropliate `target_include_directories` command should be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target_link_libraries` is to set libraries to link with when actually building the specified target. The problem here is that `INTERFACE` libraries aren't built.

You need to add the libraries to link with as a *dependency* for your library.

This is done with the [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html#command:set_target_properties) command to set the [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) property:

```
set_target_properties(foo
    PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES stdc++fs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I add a C++20 flag to this interface as well? Or is that superfluous?

Comment: @user93114 `target_compile_features` should work as you intend, I think. It should set the [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES.html) property.

Comment: @user93114 To check you can do a verbose build where the commands are shown with all flags and options.